# Django Model Choices Recommendation (Specific Setup)

Tags: django, model, choicefield

I am seeking recommendations for the setup of choices between some models.  The choices possible in one model are dependent upon a previously chosen choice of another model.

I have a product that I want to cater to two separate audiences, specifically undergraduate students and equivalent graduate students.  I'm keeping track of the School, their Year, and courses within these schools.  In this setup, students must be either Freshman, Sophomore, Junior, Senior, or Other if they're undergrads, and First, Second, Third, Fourth Year, or Other, if they're graduate students.  My question is how best to setup the foreign key choices such that when their school is specifically of type "undergrad" or "grad" this reflects in their year choices such that they are then restricted to those choices specific to their school type as previously specified.  Some example models:

```
class StudentType(models.Model):
    STUDENT_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('graduate', 'Graduate'),
        ('undergrad', 'Undergraduate'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=STUDENT_TYPE_CHOICES)


class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    student_type = models.ForeignKey(StudentType)


class Year(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=????)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, related_name="years")
```

I would appreciate filling in the `choices` parameter of the name column of the Year model.  This parameter, as previously stated, is dependent upon the school of the model.  Is this a possibility?  Should I simply combine all choices (i.e. undergrad and grad school choices) together?

Comment: Wouldn't a property function evaluating this upon your object creation or at runtime figure out what category the user belongs to?

Comment: Well, it's not the user's type you're worried about deciding, it's the School's type.  A school will have a type that will not change, so doesn't need to be computed, such as through a model property.  It's true that I could probably just do this logic manually by just carefully setting the correct `choice` from the admin panel.  That's why this is primarily a best-practices sort of question.

Comment: Okay. I guess the way you want to do this depends on where you fetch your data from. If you add each `School` manually trough the admin-panel I say that seting the type there is the best way. If you read them from some extarnal datasource(s) the best is to find a way to determine what kind of school it is and set the property based on that when you syncronize the data.

Comment: Manually through the admin panel.  Unfortunately, I'm leaving it up to a non-technical user to enter the data, thus my desire to use the choices parameter.  I guess it's just one step to make sure I've taught to them correctly :)

Comment: Unless you have no other way of checking, I guess you'll have to trust the ones creating your data...